# SquareSpace: Site Title WITH a logo ABOVE

Tags: squarespace

Is there any way I could place an image above my site title on my 'home' page? I would like a logo above the words "Bryson Price".

[HOME PAGE example](http://www.brysonprice.com/home)

I would also like my social media icons to be a little bit larger.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a lot to this.  First off you need to edit your HTML using code block http://help.squarespace.com/guides/using-the-code-block.  Then you'll need to edit your CSS using your css editor http://help.squarespace.com/guides/using-the-css-editor.  However, if you don't know how to edit html or css you have much more to learn first :)

Comment: Thanks for the response Jake!  Yes, that sounds really intense...theres no way I'll know what to do.  If someone can chime in and help, I will be EXTREMELY thankful

Comment: Sorry that it's not that simple.  You would have to upload your logo and then know the destination of that logo and then be able to add img html above your header redirecting to that logo.  As far as your social media icons are concerned...unfortunately they are icons and are set to a specific size.